# How to animate enter and leave of MeteorJS {{#if}} block?

Tags: animation, meteor, spacebars

The title really says it all. Given a template:

```
{{#if selection}}
    <div class="something">
        <p>To Animate</p>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

how do I control enter and exit animations of `.something`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a template out of the DOM containing stuff to animate:

```
<templte name="somthing">
<div class="parentdiv">
{{#if selection}}
    <div class="something">
        <p>To Animate</p>
    </div>
{{/if}}
<div>
</template>
```

You can then use _ui_hooks

```
Template.something.onRendered(function() {

this.find('#task-list')._uihooks = {
      insertElement: function(node, next) {
        $(node).addClass('animate')
          .insertBefore(next);

        setTimeout( function () {
          $(node).removeClass('animte');
        }, 20);
      },
      removeElement: function (node) {
        $(node).addClass('animate')
          .on(EVENTS, function() {
            $(node).remove()
          });
      },
    }
});
```

So here your css class containing the animation is `animate`.